# call external ASP.NET Web API as POST through _api/SP.WebProxy.invoke and return data

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a ASP.NET Web API Method with the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething(Person inputPerson)
{
 Person p = new Person("ijkl", "mnop");
 string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);     
 HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
 response.Content = new StringContent(jsonResult, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 return response;
}
```

I am calling this method through _api/SP.WebProxy.invoke  (in a custom VS workflow).  I cannot read the return values from the web method.  Is this a limitation in _api/SP.WebProxy.invoke using POST, so that you cannot read any return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this and I am posting this in-case someone else faces the same problem.  Basically once you call the service the response comes in something like **d/Invoke/Body**.  What I did was to first parse this value into a dynamic values and then extract the properties, this way I got it working.